# ERROR: Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite, mime

I am running Reactjs with vite, When I am trying to start my app with network IP I am getting the following error

[image]

I am getting the following error when I am trying to start the app with host: localhost
[image]
**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/favicon.ico" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Asset Scanner</title>
        <script
  src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.2.0/socket.io.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-PiBR5S00EtOj2Lto9Uu81cmoyZqR57XcOna1oAuVuIEjzj0wpqDVfD0JA9eXlRsj"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <div id="modals"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**src/main.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

import App from '@@/App'
import { loadCSSVariables } from './common/utils/cssVariables'

loadCSSVariables().then(() => {
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
})
```

Comment: Can you list the process you made to arrive at this point ? What commands ?

Comment: This code was written by another person. According to the instructions I gave 2 commands "npm install" and "npm run dev"

Comment: We can't find the problem without seeing the code. Please share `index.html`, `src/index`...

Comment: I have added the codes

Comment: can you comment `<div id="modals"></div>`, to see if the error change ? And then do the same with `<script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx"></script>`

Comment: while removing <div id="modals"></div> this there is no error change. When removing the second code It didn't throw any error but I cannot see any content on the webpage